# If/Else with two checkboxes checked - Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, checkbox

A real simple javascript function I'm getting stuck with...  (Have googled alot and can't make it fully work!).

Basiclly, I have two check boxes.  And I went my disclaimer to disappear, (only when both boxes have been checked.  (See full code below).

If only one/none boxes are not checked, the disclaimer should still appear.  And the form submit button is disabled.

Everything works fine.  I can make the disclaimer disappear and deactivate the button, if one box is checked. But seems to not do anything, with my if/else statement below.

Basically, the "if" in my if/else statement, is not checking for the right logic.

I've googled and tried lots of variations. But can't get this one working.
Thank you!

```
  var formInput = document.querySelector("input[name=terms]");
  var marketingInput = document.querySelector("input[name=marketing]");
  var cvSubmitButton = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  var checkBoxDiv = document.getElementById("checkboxRow");
  var scfSubmitButtonBorder = document.querySelector(".scfSubmitButtonBorder");

  cvSubmitButton.classList.add('disabled');
  scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "not-allowed";

  var legalClause = document.createElement('div');
  legalClause.innerHTML = "<div id='disclaimer'><br /><p>* Your applicaton cannot be submitted, unless you have agreed to read our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy and Cookie Policy.</p></div>";
  checkBoxDiv.appendChild(legalClause);


  // EVENTLISTENER

    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

    formInput.addEventListener("change", function(){

     if((formInput.checked) && (marketingInput.checked)) {

      cvSubmitButton.classList.remove('disabled');
      checkBoxDiv.removeChild(legalClause);
      scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "pointer";
      console.log('checked');
     } else {

      cvSubmitButton.classList.add('disabled');
      checkBoxDiv.appendChild(legalClause);
      scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
      console.log('not checked');
     }
  });
```

**AND HERE'S THE HTML SNIPPET:**

```
<div id="checkboxRow" class="scfSectionContent">
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="terms">  * I have read and agree with the <a href="/terms-of-user" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>, <a href="/privacy-policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="/cookie-policy" target="_blank">Cookie Policy</a>.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="marketing" value="marketing">  I agree that Adecco Group AG can use my details to send me information about their activities. This may be by post, email, SMS, MMS, phone, social media, push notifications in apps and other means. I understand that I may opt out at any time.
<div><div id="disclaimer"><br><p>* Your applicaton cannot be submitted, unless you have agreed to read our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy and Cookie Policy.</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: if((formInput.checked) && (marketingInput.checked)), is checking if  both condition is true, use '||', this will trigger is any one is not checked

Comment: When you listen for the change event on only one check box (`formInput`), your code will run only when that checkbox is changed (and nothing will happen when the other (`marketingInput`) is changed). Perhaps listening for change on both checkboxes might help? Also, please post a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which illustrates the problem to preclude guessing :)

Comment: It seems like you're only binding the change event listener to `formInput`, not to both `formInput` and `marketingInput`. I'm assuming you want to run the logic whenever _either_ checkbox is clicked? If so, you need to bind to both checkboxes.

Comment: Can you add some of your html, so we'll be able to have a working snippet?

Comment: Hiya, I've just added the html.  I'm working from a UAT environment, which doesn't seem to like ES6, so just an FYI :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all your advice! I managed to get it working, by adding a second event listener to the marketinginput.  (Good spot the poster!).  And definged && and || more clearly.

Here's the code.  Thank you!!!

```
  var formInput = document.querySelector("input[name=terms]");
  var marketingInput = document.querySelector("input[name=marketing]");
  var cvSubmitButton = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  var checkBoxDiv = document.getElementById("checkboxRow");
  var scfSubmitButtonBorder = document.querySelector(".scfSubmitButtonBorder");

  cvSubmitButton.classList.add('disabled');
  scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "not-allowed";

  var legalClause = document.createElement('div');
  legalClause.innerHTML = "<div id='disclaimer'><br /><p>* Your applicaton cannot be submitted, unless you have agreed to read our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy and Cookie Policy.</p></div>";
  checkBoxDiv.appendChild(legalClause);


  // EVENTLISTENER

  formInput.addEventListener("change", function(){

  if(formInput.checked && marketingInput.checked) {

    checkBoxDiv.removeChild(legalClause);
    scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "pointer";
    cvSubmitButton.classList.remove('disabled');     
    console.log('forminput - both checked checked');


  } else {
      cvSubmitButton.classList.add('disabled');
      checkBoxDiv.appendChild(legalClause);
      scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
      console.log('not checked');
  }
 });


marketingInput.addEventListener("change", function(){

  if(marketingInput.checked && formInput.checked) {

checkBoxDiv.removeChild(legalClause);
    scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "pointer";
    cvSubmitButton.classList.remove('disabled');     
    console.log('marketinginput - both checked checked');


  } else {

      cvSubmitButton.classList.add('disabled');
      checkBoxDiv.appendChild(legalClause);
      scfSubmitButtonBorder.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
      console.log('not checked');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably have two inputs checkboxes with name terms:

```
  var formInput = document.querySelector("input[name=terms]");
```

But you are accesing only one and adding event listener to only one. 
You should use querySelectorAll, and add eventListener to each one of those checkboxes.

For example:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=terms]");

Array.from(a).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log("Here");
  });
})
```

Comment: Just added the html, my name for each checkbox is different...  I'll try the map anyway. thanks

Comment: Your problem then is, that you don't check another checkbox. Look, you checked your terms, it checked if both checkboxes are checked (they are not though). You checked your second checkbox, nothing happens, because no event listener attached to it. Try checking, first second checkbox, and then first, it works.

Comment: You need to check for this condition, when either of those checkboxes are changed.

Comment: I know I need to do this, have a condition that checks both check boxes have been checked only.  But I'm not sure what the correct code is to write.  This is the problem I'm having... thank you.

Comment: You have a condition that's firing off, only for one checkbox. Extract it to a function, and pass it to both inputs onChange